# Multi-dimensional array, remove array where key and value match another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to remove duplicates where either measurement or altunit matches another array, but ignoring if they're blank.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [altunit] => %
            [measurement] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [altunit] => 
            [measurement] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [altunit] => %
            [measurement] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [altunit] => 
            [measurement] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [altunit] => 
            [measurement] => 6
        )

)
```

Becomes

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [altunit] => %
            [measurement] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [altunit] => 
            [measurement] => 6
        )

)
```

Best I can come up with is:

```
$test = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'altunit' => '%', 'measurement' => NULL, ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'altunit' => NULL, 'measurement' => '6', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'altunit' => NULL, 'measurement' => '6', ), 3 => array ( 'id' => '5', 'altunit' => NULL, 'measurement' => '6', ), 4 => array ( 'id' => '6', 'altunit' => NULL, 'measurement' => '6', ), );

$num = [];
foreach($test as $k => $v) $num[] = $v['measurement'];
```

But this only works for measurement, and removes the id and altunit keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humm,
Make an array of 'knowed value' for measurement and altunit and then check it it exist on the rest of the values.

something like:

```
$knowed_altunit=array();
$knowed_measurement=array();

foreach($test as $k=>$v){
  if(in_array($v['altunit'],$knowed_altunit) 
  || in_array($v['mesurement'],$knowed_measurement)){
    //if the value of altunit or measurement is already knowed then remove the entry from the array,
    unset($test[$k]);
  }else{
   //if it never been seen, add it so further entry can be checked agaisnt the knowed value
   $knowed_altunit[]=$v['altunit'];
   $knowed_measurement[]=$v['mesurement'];
  }
}
```

Sorry if any typo but thins might help you wrap your head around the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
<?php

    /* before you need to check that $test variable is declarated and have all items to check */
    $values_altunit = array();
    $values_measurement = array();
    $result = array();

    foreach($test as $key => $value) {
        /* check if exist altunit and measurement values in blacklist arrays */
        if (!in_array($value['altunit'], $values_altunit) && !in_array($value['measurement'], $values_measurement)) {
            /* if not exist, add the item to $result array */
            $result[$key] = $value;
            /* and add altunit and measurement values to blacklist arrays */
            $values_altunit[] = $value['altunit'];
            $values_measurement[] = $value['measurement'];
        }
    }

    /* print result items */
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same logic as my answer but i think blacklist is a better name :P Apart from the fact that this answer requires a new array instead of unsetting value from the original array.

Comment: Yes, our answers are similar but i'm creating a new array instead of unset values.. The difference in our answer time are seconds :)

Comment: I like to keep my memory_get_usage() low, this is why i rather unset value from an existing array than create a new one and duplicate values. Personal preference, just saying :) I still upvoted your answer :P

Answer (score 1):

This is a short code that can give the result for unique measurements

```
  <?php 

    $arr = array(
        "0"=> array        (
                "id" => 2,
                "altunit" => "%",
                "measurement" => "",
            ),

        "1"=> array        (
                "id" => 3,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 6,
            ),

        "2"=> array        (
                "id" => 4,
                "altunit" => "%",
                "measurement" => "",
            ),

        "3"=> array        (
                "id" => 5,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 6,
            ),

        "4"=> array        (
                "id" => 6,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 6,
            )

    );

    $unique_measure = $new_array  = array();
    foreach($arr as $sup_key => $sup_val){
        foreach($sup_val as $sub_key => $sub_val){
            if(!in_array($sup_val['measurement'], $unique_measure)){
                array_push($unique_measure, $sup_val['measurement']);
                array_push($new_array,$sup_val);

            }

        }
    }

    print_r($new_array);
?>
```

> Output :

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [altunit] => %
                [measurement] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [altunit] => 
                [measurement] => 6
            )

    )
```

try this code. it may do the trick.

One More approach to your problems solution can be removing that particular key from the main array using  `unset(your_array_key)` will do the trick in the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Try, this may help you

```
function remove_dup($array, $keys )
{
    $out = array();

    foreach($array as $sub)
    {
        if(empty($out))
        {   
            $out[] = $sub;
            continue;
        }

        foreach($keys as $key)
        {   
            if($flag=in_array( $sub[$key],array_map(function($e) use($key){ return $e[$key];}, $out)) )
                break;
        }

        if(!$flag)
            $out[] = $sub;
    }

    return $out;
}

// Usage
print_r( remove_dup($array, array('altunit','measurement') ) );
```

**Test**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

function remove_dup($array, $keys )
{
    $out = array();

    foreach($array as $sub)
    {
        if(empty($out))
        {   
            $out[] = $sub;
            continue;
        }

        foreach($keys as $key)
        {   
            if($flag=in_array( $sub[$key],array_map(function($e) use($key){ return $e[$key];}, $out)) )
                break;
        }

        if(!$flag)
            $out[] = $sub;
    }

    return $out;
}

$array = array(
        "0"=> array      (
                "id" => 2,
                "altunit" => "%",
                "measurement" => "",
            ),

        "1"=> array        (
                "id" => 3,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 6,
            ),

        "2"=> array        (
                "id" => 4,
                "altunit" => "%",
                "measurement" => "",
            ),

        "3"=> array        (
                "id" => 5,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 4,
            ),

        "4"=> array        (
                "id" => 6,
                "altunit" => "",
                "measurement" => 6,
            )

    );

print_r( remove_dup($array, array('altunit','measurement') ) );


?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [altunit] => %
            [measurement] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [altunit] => 
            [measurement] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a **set**, not an array. So if you can't fix the way you're building the array in the first place (*my guess is this came from an SQL query, which would be a lot less code to rectify*) you have two options for creating mapped sets in PHP.

1. You could use `SplObjectStorage`
2. You could use an `Array` with the key as a *serialized* representation of the set

The first approach would look something like this...

```
$set = new SplObjectStorage();

$arr = [
    0 => [
        'id'          => '2',
        'altunit'     => '%',
        'measurement' => NULL,
    ],
    1 => [
        'id'          => '3',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    2 => [
        'id'          => '4',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    3 => [
        'id'          => '5',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    4 => [
        'id'          => '6',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
];

foreach($arr as $part) {
    if (isset($part['altunit'])) { // ignore if blank
        $key = (object) $part;
        $set->attach($key); // attach the set
    }
}

// Now you have...
foreach($set as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

This would give you...

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["altunit"]=>
  string(1) "%"
  ["measurement"]=>
  NULL
}
```

The second approach, using an array, where the array key represents a serialized version of the set would look something like this...

```
$set = [];

$arr = [
    0 => [
        'id'          => '2',
        'altunit'     => '%',
        'measurement' => NULL,
    ],
    1 => [
        'id'          => '3',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    2 => [
        'id'          => '4',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    3 => [
        'id'          => '5',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
    4 => [
        'id'          => '6',
        'altunit'     => NULL,
        'measurement' => '6',
    ],
];

foreach($arr as $part) {
    if (isset($part['altunit'])) { // ignore if blank
        $key = "{$part['altunit']}\0{$part['measurement']}";
        $set[$key] = $part; // attach the set
    }
}

// Now you have...
foreach($set as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

And that would give you...

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["altunit"]=>
  string(1) "%"
  ["measurement"]=>
  NULL
}
```

### N.B

But, if this is a result set from an SQL query it's quite possible you could just more effectively eliminate the de-duplication process entirely by modifying the query to use `WHERE NOT NULL` and `GROUP BY` clauses instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this also
 <?php
      $keys    = array_map(function ($i) { return $i; }, $array);
      $dumparr = array_combine($keys, $array);
      $result  = array_values($deduped);
      print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: What it does basically ?